# connection close or what the problem with cron

Tags: django, cron, cron-task

I have success doing daily backup code by crontab -e like this
sshpass -p "password" scp user@ip:/bath /bathto/bakup/$(date +%H:%M_%Y-%m-%d).sql

but Only an incomplete part of the file been transferred when the task work, the full file size about 170M but the the transferred fille come 70-100M maximum .

how to make cron transfer the file completely when the task run?